# Infer types when using type guard in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeguards

```js
interface A = {
  name: string;
  ...
};

interface B = {
  name: string;
  ...
};

interface C = {
  key: string;
  ...
};

type UnionOfTypes = A | B | C | ...;

function hasName(item: UnionOfTypes) {
  if ("name" in item) {
    item; // typescript knows here that item is either A or B
  }
}
```

Is there some way that I can infer types in the same way that `if("name" in item)` does it? I don't have classes only interfaces/types.

So that I don't have to explicitly say

```js
function hasName(item: UnionOfTypes): item is A | B {
  ...
}
```

The reasoning behind this is that I want to use other type guards deeper down, or is there some other reason why I should avoid narrowing down types this way?

Comment: There is no auto inference for type guards. You have to write it explicitly

Comment: So my only option would be to go for the if-statement inline given that I want the type guard to happen correctly and don't end up with multiple unions in different places?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for this by default in typescript. You can create a helper function that creates a type guard. The function passed to this helper function will return the guarded item, or `false`.

```
function guard<T extends I, I>(fn: (value: I) => T | false)  {
    return function (value: I) : value is T {
        return fn(value) !== false
    }
}

interface A {
  name: string;
  a: number;
};

interface B {
  name: string;
  b: number;
};

interface C {
  key: string;
};

type UnionOfTypes = A | B | C ;

const hasName = guard(function (item: UnionOfTypes) {
  if ("name" in item) {
    return item;
  }
  return false;
})


// Works for other casses too
let numberOrNull: Array<string | null> = ["", null]
let r = numberOrNull.filter(guard(v => v ?? false));
let r2 = numberOrNull.filter(guard(v => v ?? false));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcxAQwE4BMA8AVRAUwA8pCwsBnRASQBpaA+ACmDAC5FmA3NAGxCFONAJSIAvI0QEAPomD9KhMYgDeAWABQiHYgyEoIDElCRYCLrwFDaYzlcGIY1Ahu26P+w8flge-QTEAQnFxeUVCLQ8AXy1YzS0YMDIMBQhCRABBNSjEMDQAWxtKKAwk5ABuXLROMBACgCNCDCrNaNbE5Oa0jIAhHPd8os4SsrBK3Iba+qaWuI7NJJSexABhAZ0Aa0IATxHS8tb2rS0oHYAHDIBVMHgwAHlgPAvCajDsuX65dYWIBBLEAALNCUAByhQyYVQmCwrHA0DuXBgZAKnBud0ez0ulDEbh0MGAXAARENCESnEhkYQCrjcjovEZKSjWjp4vSDIzwnwlEcRCcEpoAPSCxAAdTgGE21GAEsQcCggOaiAgIKU1CgcDgWj4BjyM2a9wwoJAfD4nEyGAwaB2OFG5UQcjqpqkYQA2kSiQwnXwALra3UYCR6xoGo0mvgAOmAMD4KWY0OwPAkUm4iAA-GmuUoRCJWjqoHoAExBuohjCG42mqMxuMJ2GpySIVMZrPKXP8oA)